# Horiz LinearLayout containing two spinners not displayed

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to assemble an Android display consisting of a seekBar at the bottom surmounted by two adjacent spinners contained in a horizontal linearLayout.   It looks okay in the design view, but the two spinners fail to display in the running app.

I appreciate any help to isolate my stupidity.

[image: Design Tab Image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.rotiferian.MainActivity">

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLeft"
        android:gravity="start"
        style="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
        android:popupBackground="#ff2f50"
        android:background="#ce243f"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerRight"
        android:gravity="end"
        style="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
        android:background="#ff4eff2f"
        android:popupBackground="#ff4eff2f"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />


</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:max="1000"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff000000"/>
```

Comment: Did you set Adapter for your Spinners?

Comment: Without adapter spinner would not be show

Comment: Thanks Bahodirov - I will try it.